# Why does ":is()" selector in CSS not seem to work?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can't figure out why `:is()` selector isn't working in any of the ways I try. It just doesn't seem to respond, so I'm bound to use these silly selector lists-

```
#top-section a:first-of-type:hover, #download-section a:first-of-type:hover,
#top-section a:last-child:hover, #download-section a:last-child:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
```

I used the syntax just as mentioned on the documentations but can't figure out what's wrong-

```
:is(#top-section, #download-section) a:first-of-type:hover,
:is(#top-section, #download-section) a:last-child:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: it still has no support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_is

Comment: what does **78** score mean in firefox area on **mdn browser compatibility**?

Comment: it's the version of the Browser, not a score. If you have Firefox V78 then you can have this working. all the other versions are Red so no support (or partial support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this selector is future proposal and we will need to wait quite some time until it will be supported by all major browsers.
For now most powerful thing for such cases (and overall CSS clarity and maintenance) is CSS preprocessor such as SASS.

You could easily achieve the same with SCSS syntax (using SASS preprocessor).
Code would look like this:

```
#top-section, #download-section{
    a:first-of-type:hover, a:last-child:hover{
       opacity: .8;
       transition: opacity .2s ease;
    }
}
```

Preprocessor would do all the dirty work for you and compile this code to:

```
#top-section a:first-of-type:hover, #top-section a:last-child:hover, #download-section a:first-of-type:hover, #download-section a:last-child:hover {
   opacity: 0.8;
   transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

You can install it  as easy as `npm install -g sass` and setup file watcher to compile sass to css automatically on every change.

If you still don't want to use css preprocessor, cleaner approach would be to use classes instead of id selectors.

Comment: actually I've used SASS a few times (it's just been 2 months in web development), but while working with React, I feel managing separate _css_ files seems less complex then managing _scss_ and their corresponding _compiled-css_ files. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have to maintain compiled files, then something is definitely wrong with project setup. If you choose to work with scss, then you should not bother about css, since tools like webpack does it for you and puts everything compiled in dist (or whatever) directory. I'm an angular developer, but know people who works with react and scss and haven't heard any maintenance problems at all.